# How to verify setting a property on an interface

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I have the following interface

```
   export interface Command {
   id: CommandId;
   disabled: boolean;
}
```

I would like to test that disabled has been called/changed on it. I tried the following:

1) Create an object and check if the property has been changed:

```
const command1: Command = {id: CommandId.Print, disabled: false};
// some stuff inbetween (see below)
expect(command1.disabled).toBe(true);
```

Result:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of undefined
```

2) Create a Mock using typemock:

```
const command1 = Mock.ofType<Command>();
command1.setup(x => x.id).returns(() => CommandId.Print);
// some stuff inbetween (see below)
command1.verify(x => x.disabled, Times.once());
```

Result:

```
TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property 'disabled'
```

3) Using spyOnProperty:

```
const command1 = {id: CommandId.Print, disabled: false} as Command;
spyOnProperty(command1, 'disabled');
// some stuff following (see below)
```

Result:

Error: Property disabled does not have access type get

I'm out of ideas, how does one verify stuff like this? 
(I'm new to Angular and typescript)

the whole test method:

```
// arrange
const command1 = {id: TaskCommandId.Print, disabled: false} as Command;
spyOnProperty(command1, 'disabled');
const command2 = {id: CommandId.SaveTemplate, disabled: false } as Command;
spyOnProperty(command2, 'disabled');

const commands = [command1, command2];
mockService.setup(x => x.getCommands()).returns(() => commands);
const command1Update = {id: CommandId.Print, disabled: true } as CommandState;
component.ngOnInit();

// act
component.updateEnabledState(command1Update);

// assert
expect(command1.disabled).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(command2.disabled).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Can you show your whole test file?

Comment: @PaulPicard updated

Comment: @IgorMeszaros there are a couple of issues with your question. It is not clear what exactly are you asking, first you show one piece of code, then absolutely different one, which one does not work, exactly?
Additionally, `expect(command1).toHaveBeenCalled();` doesn't make sense, since you expect object to be called? Functions can be called, but objects cannot.

Comment: @YuriyKravets I want to know how to validate that the disabled property has been modified in test. None of the 3 ways I tried worked, the last bit of code is my entire test with using spyOnProperty as I said in the 3rd example. `expect(command1).toHaveBeenCalled();` is an error on my part I'll correct it

Comment: @IgorMeszaros `toHaveBeenCalled()` expects a function, not an object or a property of an object. example usage of `toHaveBeenCalled()` would be with `component.updateEnabledState`. Full example: `expect(component.updateEnabledState).toHaveBeenCalled();`. If you want to check if the property `command1.disabled` was changed, then you should call function that changes it (I suspect it's what `updateEnabledState` does), and then `expect(command1.disabled).toBeFalse();`.

Comment: @IgorMeszaros it would be easier if you would share your working example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1afsqt), that way we can see the full picture of what is happening and help you find a solution.

Comment: @YuriyKravets actually I got it to work as you suggested `expect(command1.disabled).toBeFalse();` initially this didn't work as I forgot to call `OnInit();`. Thanks for your help

Comment: @IgorMeszaros added an answer, accept it if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toHaveBeenCalled()` is meant to check whether the function was called, for example:

```
spyOn(component, 'someFn').and.callThrough();
component.ngOnInit();
expect(component.someFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

The above should work having the call to `someFn` inside `ngOnInit` in your component, for example:

```
ngOnInit() {
    someFn();
}
someFn() {
    console.log('1');
}
```

To check whether some `property` of an object was changed or not, you have to check that exact property, for example:

```
component.obj = {disabled: false};
component.ngOnInit();
expect(component.obj.disabled).toBeTrue();
```

The above should work with the following code in your component:

```
obj: any;
ngOnInit() {
    this.obj.disabled = true;
}
```